# Pandas, subsorting/ordering a grouped series within a super-date/series

Tags: python, pandas

Kind of at a loss for words as to how to describe. I have a dataset that I want to keep in datetime order but somehow the hour value got jumbled and I'd liked it be in ascending order as well, 1,2,3.... I've tried df.group(['XX','hour']).sort_by('hour'); and using .groupby().size('hour'). Not seeing how to do it without breaking apart the XX values.

What I've got now...

```
id ## datetime ## hour ##  XX ##     YY

0     2018/01/01  2       chairs      5  
1     2018/01/01  1       chairs      3
2     2018/01/01  3       chairs      6
3     2018/01/01  3       tables      7
4     2018/01/01  1       tables      9 
5     2018/01/01  2       tables      2
6     2018/01/02  2       chairs      2
7     2018/01/02  1       chairs      3
8     2018/01/02  3       chairs      6
9     2018/01/02  2       tables      2
10    2018/01/02  3       tables      3
11    2018/01/02  1       tables      5
```

What I've been aiming for...

```
id ## datetime ## hour ##  XX ##     YY

0     2018/01/01  1       chairs      3  
1     2018/01/01  2       chairs      5
2     2018/01/01  3       chairs      6
3     2018/01/01  1       tables      9
4     2018/01/01  2       tables      2 
5     2018/01/01  3       tables      7
6     2018/01/02  1       chairs      3
7     2018/01/02  2       chairs      2
8     2018/01/02  3       chairs      6
9     2018/01/02  1       tables      5
10    2018/01/02  2       tables      2
11    2018/01/02  3       tables      3
```

Apologies for the funky diagram, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper key by using `cumcount` , then `sort_values`

```
new_df=df.assign(helperkey=df.groupby('hour').cumcount()).sort_values(['datetime','helperkey','hour'])
new_df
Out[524]: 
    id    datetime  hour      XX  YY  helperkey
1    1  2018/01/01     1  chairs   3          0
0    0  2018/01/01     2  chairs   5          0
2    2  2018/01/01     3  chairs   6          0
4    4  2018/01/01     1  tables   9          1
5    5  2018/01/01     2  tables   2          1
3    3  2018/01/01     3  tables   7          1
7    7  2018/01/02     1  chairs   3          2
6    6  2018/01/02     2  chairs   2          2
8    8  2018/01/02     3  chairs   6          2
11  11  2018/01/02     1  tables   5          3
9    9  2018/01/02     2  tables   2          3
10  10  2018/01/02     3  tables   3          3
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.